# Get the id of the row from database on click of a button

Tags: php, mysql

I am using wordpress and I am fetching images from the mysql database with below code. And I display the image and there is a button just with every image and what I want is that when that button is pressed the id of that row of database that is fetched is printed on the screen.

Code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 1user";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>'.'<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Upvote"></form>';    

}

if(isset($_POST['show'])){

echo "<br>".$result->path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like your sample:

```
$results = array(
    (object)array('id'=>1, 'path'=>'data:image/jpeg;base64,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'),
    (object)array('id'=>2, 'path'=>'data:image/jpeg;base64,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')   
);
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$result->id.'">';
    echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>'.'<input type="submit" name="show" id="show" value="Upvote">';
    echo '</form>';
}

if(isset($_POST['show'])){
    $id = (isset($_POST['id'])) ? intval($_POST['id']): null;
    echo "<br>".$id;
}
```

With javascript

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo '<img src="'.$result->path.'" width="150" height="150" data-id="'.$result->id.'">';
}

<script>
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    image.onclick = function(event) {
        alert(this.dataset.id);
    };
}
</script>
```